# django multitenant architecture options: what influence on database performance?

Tags: django, database, performance, schema

I m designing a website where security of data is an issue.
I ve read this book : https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/index.html

I'm still thinking about the right database structure for users.
And im hesitating between shared database with isolated schemas, isolated databases in a shared app, or completely isolated tenants using docker.

As security of data is an issue, i would like to avoid to put all the users in the same table in the database or in different schemas in the same database. However i dont understand well if i should put each user in a separate database (create a database per user, sqlite for example but i dont know if it would communicate well with postgres). What is the best practice for this in terms of security?
Im wondering how these options affect database speed compared to a shared database with a shared schema, which was the basic configuration of the course i attended on django.

I dont have good knowledge on databases so your help on the performance issue would be very appreciated!

Also, if I want to do some stats and use tenants data, how difficult is it to query completely isolated tenants using docker or isolated databases, in particular if each user is a separate docker or database?

Comment: did you manage to figure something out? I'm now researching the same solutions as you were. Thank you!

Comment: i was told using schema is a useless hassle and that putting the users in the same table was ok provided the sql query was enough security to isolate data regarding regulations...